# How can I properly call emgucv retrieve command in Visual C++?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-forms-designer, emgucv

I'm trying to translate a piece of code from visual c# to visual c++ and can't seem to translate this bit:

```
Mat m = new Mat();
capture.Retrieve(m);
pictureBox1.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;
```

so far i've written

```
Mat^ m = gcnew Mat();
Emgu::CV::Capture::Retrieve(m);
pictureBox1->Image = m->ToImage<Bgr, Byte>()->Bitmap;
```

but i get the following errors

> (E1767    function "Emgu::CV::Capture::Retrieve" cannot be called with the given argument list)

> (E0304    no instance of function template "Emgu::CV::Mat::ToImage" matches the argument list)

Any help would be appreciated.